# Python/Pandas - Different label colors on stacked bar

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

I would like to change the label color of the first block (dark color one) in each column for a better visualization. Is there any way?

ps: I wouldn't want to change the current color palette. Just the color label of the first block!

[image]

Code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context({"figure.figsize": (7, 5)})

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
           columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True, cmap="cividis", alpha=1, edgecolor="black")
sns.despine(top=False, right=True, left=False, bottom=True)

#add text
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height =  p.get_bbox().bounds
    if height > 0 :
        ax.annotate("{0:.0f}".format(height), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), ha='center', va='center')
```

Comment: You mean the first block (dark color one) in each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same color map and change label color, you could specify `color` parameter in `annotate` function as follows.

```
 ax.annotate("{0:.0f}".format(height), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), ha='center', va='center', color="white")
```

There are other configs such as font size etc.
The first block means `1, 4, 7` blocks in the array. Therefore, you could extract the first row of the data frame and check if height is one of the cell values using `np.isin()` like;

```
firstblocks = (df.iloc[:, 0])
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds

    if np.isin(p.get_height(), firstblocks):
        ax.annotate("{0:.0f}".format(height), xy=(left + width / 2, bottom + height / 2), ha='center', va='center',
                    color="white", fontsize=12)
    else:
        ax.annotate("{0:.0f}".format(height), xy=(left + width / 2, bottom + height / 2), ha='center', va='center')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

I really wouldn't want to change the current color palette. 
If possible, I would just like to change the label color of the first block to be visible...

Comment: Please put that in the question, otherwise how do we know?

Comment: The color parameter in the 'annotate' applies to all blocks.
If possible, I would just like to change the label color of the first block to be visible...

There any way to specify only the label color of the first block?

Comment: Have a look now.

Comment: Yes, It's a way! 
But it works only when the dataset does not have duplicate values such as [1,1.1].

Maybe the best solution is try use the dataframe column name instead manual values. I'll try again with that in mind..

Comment: The stackoverflow answers are usually a good guidance. We cannot write the whole program considering all your constraints. You could start with that and explore how to detect the first block more elegantly.

Comment: That's for sure. 

That is why I will try, from that point, to seek a solution to detect the first block more elegantly and, if I can, share again on that forum with you and people who may have the same problem but with distinct data-sets.

I really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: No worries. Please do post your findings.

Comment: Got! 
I noticed that the pandas draw the stacked graphics starting with the first 'block' on all axes, to then start over. 
For this reason, as I wish to only change the color of the first block, it is enough that only the first N have the color changed. 

Just changed that part of your solution.
 
`n=0
for p in ax.patches:
    n=n+1
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    if n <= len(df.index) `
          
The remainder was the same. 
Thanks for the help. I'll consider solved.

Comment: @MarcosFreitas great. I’ll add your findings in the answer.

Comment: @MarcosFreitas updated the answer following your hint. But found a better way of check the first row cells.